# Spring Security + Thymeleaf как проверить пользователя на аутентификацию

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, аутентификация

Делаю веб-приложение на Spring Boot с Spring Security и Thymeleaf. Будет несколько динамических страниц (потом собираюсь сделать с JavaScript), на каждой из которых должна будет отображаться либо форма для входа и кнопка регистрации (если пользователь не аутентифицирован), либо приветствие и кнопка выхода (если аутентифицирован). В общем все как на обычных сайтах. Так вот как с помощью Spring Security и/или Thymeleaf сделать проверку пользователя на аутентифицированность таким образом, чтобы условие проверки не пришлось впихивать в каждый метод контроллера или каждое представление html? Сделать какой-то Security фильтр? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прям как вы хотите, наверно не выйдет. Допустим информация о том залогинился ли юзер или нет представленна только в шапке. Спрингу в любом случае перед отображением любого view нужно будет проверять аутентификацию пользователя. Поэтому придется создать шапку для каждого случая. Используя Thymeleaf Spring Security Dialect это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>user@ukr.net</p> <a href="/logout">Logout</a> //вариант шапки если аутентифицирован  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> //вариант шапки если не аутентифицирован 
</div>
```

вы можете этот кусок как вставлять на каждую свою страницу. Либо вынести его в отдельное место (допустим в переменную String **header** или куда вам будет удобней). И просто передавать этот header на каждую страницу (шапка ж везде одинаковая, на сколько я понимаю). То есть на каждой странице у вас будет просто значение переменной **header** без всяких if-else, но за кулисами при загрузке каждой страницы Спринг будет проверять аутентификацию. Только не забудьте, обязательно, включить диалект. Добавьте в свой проперти файл:

```
spring.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.enabled=true
```